# Why do Humans not produce Vitamin C like other mammals?

Tags: human-biology, vitamins

Why do most mammals produce their own Vitamin C?

Why do Humans not?

Comment: See the last two paragraphs of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-gulonolactone_oxidase#Consequences_of_loss for two alternate hypotheses.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Humans do not produce Vitamin C due to a mutation in the GULO (gulonolactone oxidase) gene, which results in the inability to synthesize the protein.  Normal GULO is an enzyme that catalyses the reaction of D-glucuronolactone with oxygen to L-xylo-hex-3-gulonolactone.  This then spontaneously forms Ascorbic Acid (Vitamin C).  However without the GULO enzyme, no vitamin C is produced.

This has not been selected against in natural selection as we are able to consume more than enough vitamin C from our diet.  It is also suggested that organisms without a functional GULO gene have a method of "recycling" the vitamin C that they obtain from their diets using red blood cells (see [Montel-Hagen et al. 2008](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016%2Fj.cell.2008.01.042)).

A 2008 published study ([Li et al. 2008](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18764764)) claimed to have successfully re-instated the ability to produce vitamin C in mice.

Simply as trivia: other than humans; guinea pigs, bats and dry-nosed primates have lost their ability to produce vitamin C in the same way.

---

**References**

- Li, Y., Shi, C.-X., Mossman, K.L., Rosenfeld, J., Boo, Y.C. &
  Schellhorn, H.E. (2008) Restoration of vitamin C synthesis in
  transgenic Gulo-/- mice by helper-dependent adenovirus-based
  expression of gulonolactone oxidase. Human gene therapy. [Online] 19
  (12), 1349–1358. Available from: doi:10.1089/hgt.2008.106 [Accessed:
  31 December 2011].
- Montel-Hagen, A., Kinet, S., Manel, N., Mongellaz, C., Prohaska, R.,
  Battini, J.-L., Delaunay, J., Sitbon, M. & Taylor, N. (2008)
  Erythrocyte Glut1 Triggers Dehydroascorbic Acid Uptake in Mammals
  Unable to Synthesize Vitamin C. Cell. [Online] 132 (6), 1039–1048.
  Available from: doi:10.1016/j.cell.2008.01.042 [Accessed: 31 December
  2011].

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141321/discussion-on-answer-by-rory-m-why-do-humans-not-produce-vitamin-c-like-other-ma).